# Python - How to add a single bracket to the beginning and end of a list

Tags: python, list, insert

So I'm to return `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]` using `L = [1,2,3,4,5]` as the starting list

Everytime I try using

```
a = [1  
L.insert(0,a)
```

to get the first bracket or use

```
L.append(]}
```

to get the last bracket, I just get ... in the command prompt like it's an if/else statement.

I know I can use just `L.extend(L)` to get the 1,2,3,4,5 added at the end, but I'm not quite sure how to get the brackets in without adding a `''` marks around them.

Comment: Welcome to SO - please format your question properly using the code tags (`{}').

Comment: Brackets are not part of the list, but a notation

Answer (score 4):

You are currently inserting L at an index in *itself*, hence the `[...]` syntax. Instead, use `*` to expand the list:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5] 
new_l = [L*2]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Huh, didnt know lists had the `operator*`. Touche.

Comment: @pstatix (almost) all sequences implement the `*` operator as *reptition*. so `str`, `tuple`, `bytes`, `bytearray`.... `range` cannot thouhgh

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Interesting. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2):

From the look of what you are asking I think you are confused on what the `[]` are.  They denote the use of a list. So to get two of them, put the list in a list.

```
L=[1,2,3,4,5]
new_L=[L*2]
print(new_L)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are trying to alter the actual display, but:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
L2 = L + L
L = [L2]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just nest L into a new list and then multiply L by the number of times you want to repeat it:

```
L = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
A = [ L * 2 ]
```

Should print

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```